# How small can you get a stream of molten steel to be at low pressure?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, metallurgy, metals, experimental-physics

I'm designing a crucible / extruder, and right now it has a .6mm hole to extrude from. Will this work? A chart with various metals listed would be nice.

Pictures:
<sub>*Click to expand*</sub>

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Keep this one. Do you want the steel to be liquid coming out or solid?

Comment: The Length/Diameter of 66 would be very difficult to machine. Typically anything over 30 is impossible/ requires special circumstances. Do you need it to be that long for cooling?

Comment: I can adjust the L/D.  I just guessed when designing this in FreeCAD.

Comment: Liquid, that rapidly gets cooled to solid.

Comment: @Rick  What L/D (for the hole at the small end) do you recommend to make this manufacturable out of ceramic?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this device? What is the end product supposed to be? Small particles, beads, a wire or strand? Something else entirely? Also you will need precise temperature control to avoid freezing in the extruder. The extruder should be made from something like graphite or it may weld/erode/contaminate the steel. Keep in mind steel is usually cast at 2900 F

Comment: @starrise I heard graphite will only work for Silver / Gold, but I'm interested in engineering metal like aluminum / steel.   Controlling the temperature is trivial at this point, I just need to design something that can work at this point, under some conditions.

Comment: @starrise, small paticles, the smaller the better.  Their shape doesn't matter as long as they're small enough.

Comment: I'd edit that into your question as it will help guide the best answers. Graphite is used for continuously cast steel, so I don't immediately see why it wouldn't work for a spray nozzle. Also, devices exist that are designed to atomize molten metals for research purposes and for producing the raw material used in powder metallurgy. It might help you to search for such devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making a nozzle with that long and thin of a hole is not feasible, but you could make a larger hole behind it and just have the last 3mm be 0.6mm in diameter. This would be feasible in a ceramic, but due to cost, I might make the nozzle into an insert that goes into a larger piece made of cheaper material.

Things to be concerned with:

- [Stream breakup due to surface tension.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension#The_breakup_of_streams_into_drops)
- Flow velocity/pressure
- Heat transfer
- Manufacturability

Each of those could be their own question, answerable by people with different expertise. So I'd recommend asking them separately.